# Binding to an Ember.Select within atemplate loop

Tags: ember.js, model-binding, handlebars.js

I have a scenarios that requires binding the value of data (generally retrieved at run time) to form element. In this case the element is an Ember.Select which will be rendered repeatedly for an arbitrary length data set.

The jsFiddle can be found here [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/urDtrain/Yt7u7/66/)

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{#each App.simpleSelectionArray.content}}
{{this.firstName}}
  {{view Ember.Select
         contentBinding="App.peopleController.content"
         selectionBinding="this"
         optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
         optionValuePath="content.id"}}

  <p>Selected: {{this.fullName}}
    (ID: {{this.id}})</p>
{{/each}}

{{#each App.selectionArray.content}}
{{this.person.firstName}}
  {{view Ember.Select
         contentBinding="App.peopleController.content"
         selectionBinding="this.person"
         optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
         optionValuePath="content.id"}}

  <p>Selected: {{this.person.fullName}}
    (ID: {{this.person.id}})</p>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

​

```js
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,

    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + " " + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName').cacheable()
});


App.peopleController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [
        App.Person.create({id: 1,firstName: 'Yehuda',lastName: 'Katz'}),
        App.Person.create({id: 2,firstName: 'Tom',lastName: 'Dale'}),
        App.Person.create({id: 3,firstName: 'Peter',lastName: 'Wagenet'}),
        App.Person.create({id: 4,firstName: 'Erik',lastName: 'Bryn'})
    ]
});

App.simpleSelectionArray = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [
         App.peopleController.objectAt(1)
    ]});

App.selectionArray = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [
         {
            id: '2',
            person: Ember.computed(function(key, value) {
                if (arguments.length === 1){
                    var personId = this.get('id');
                    console.log(personId);
                    var listedPerson = App.peopleController.content.findProperty("id", personId);
                    return listedPerson ;
                 }else{
                     this.set(key,value);
                     return value;
                 }
            }).property('id').cacheable() 
        },                     
    ]});

​
```

The two generated select elements are based on different data structures. The first (mostly) behave as expected, except for the binding post selection.

The second data structure, which will be more typical, is not working for me at all.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand your question: You have an array of items over which you want to iterate and inside each iteration you want to show a `<select/>` which' options are the same for every item, and you can choose an item from this `select` which is then stored on the item itself? Now I don't know if I made my question clear. Hmmm..

Comment: In the actual application my data consists of a set of rules, that each contain a variable number of conditions. The conditions are built from the same select options: rule:{considtions:[]}

Comment: The data (hopefully bound from the select) is then available for save or other operations. Since both arrays are variable in length there is no way that I know of to bind using a global path like most of the other examples show. So here I'm trying to bind to the local template context inside the {{#each}} loop - which should? bind to the original condition that sets it default value.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of the resulting HTML structure you want to get? Is this accurate: http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/XpPTz/?

Answer (score 0):

I had some syntax issues, and needed to provide a setter for the bound item. A working version can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/urDtrain/tUxpm/)

html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each App.selectedPersonController.content}}
    {{this.personId}}
      {{view Ember.Select
             contentBinding="App.peopleController.content"
             selectionBinding="person"
             optionLabelPath="content.fullName"
             optionValuePath="content.id"}}

      <p>Selected: {{person.fullName}}
        (ID: {{person.id}})</p>

    {{/each}}
</script>​
```

script

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

Ember.ArrayProxy.reopen({
    /**
     * returns either an item or index for the current array based on a
     * requested field name and value
     *
     * @param fieldName
     * @param value
     * @param type
     */
    getItemFromField: function(fieldName, value, isIndex){
        var index = -1, aData = this.toArray();

        for(var i= 0, max=aData.length; i<max ; i++){
            var item = aData[i];
            if(item.hasOwnProperty(fieldName) && item[fieldName].toString() === value.toString()){
                if(isIndex){
                    return i;
                }
                return this.objectAt(i);
            }
        }

        if(isIndex){
            return -1;
        }
        return null;
    }
});

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,

    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + " " + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName').cacheable()
});

App.selectedPersonController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content:[Ember.Object.create({
        personId: 2,

        person: function(item, value) {
            if(arguments.length === 1){
                var personId = this.get('personId');
                person = App.peopleController.getItemFromField("id", personId);
                return person;
            }else{
                return value;
            }
        }.property('personId').cacheable()
    })]
    });


App.peopleController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [
        App.Person.create({
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'Yehuda',
        lastName: 'Katz'
    }),
        App.Person.create({
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'Tom',
        lastName: 'Dale'
    }),
        App.Person.create({
        id: 3,
        firstName: 'Peter',
        lastName: 'Wagenet'
    }),
        App.Person.create({
        id: 4,
        firstName: 'Erik',
        lastName: 'Bryn'
    })
        ]
});​
```

My basic concern was binding to contexts that are not bound to Global variables that have a fixed path, but are generated by nesting.